# Internship starts before school ends

Tags: communication, job-offer, internship, conflict, start-date

I have an offer for an internship a while ago but I haven't accept it yet. My internship starts on June 6 but my school's quarter ends on June 10 and I also have final exams on June 10 also. What do I do in this case? Who should I talk to? It's an out of state internship and I have to relocate so I cannot work while going to school. I have yet to received a formal.offer letter yet and they said they will send it one week from today

My internship is really like a 10-wk program (they framed it like this) so it seems like a fixed length program.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere No I just got the offer like yesterday and I didn't know the start day until then. Should have asked the recruiter on the phone when she tell me the offer but I forgot

Comment: Talk to either the hiring manager or the recruiter at the company. He/she certainly can help you out by delaying your start date for the internship till after your final exam. The sooner you let them know, the better it is.

Comment: As you have not yet accepted this internship, find another in your own area that starts after the school end.

Comment: @SolarMike I am trying to but CS internships are very competitive and many companies ends their internship recruiting cycle before March. Submitted like 150 applications and only got 3 final rounds

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a few options:

- Ask the school
- Ask the company

It can be possible to take an exam early, or substitute a project for the exam. Ask your academic counselor for advice regarding how to ask, and if there are any forms.  You might have more success if the internship will also gain you academic credit.  Because of the move to online learning over the last few years it may also be possible to take exams online.   Moving one exam is easier then moving multiple exams.

The company might have flexibility. I know of a major company who kicks off a new batch of interns every Monday from mid-May until late June. They do this because every college has a different end of term in the spring, and a different start of term in the fall. You might have to wait until the offer letter to see if they have flexibility. Your POC in the internship program will know if it is possible to shift by a week.

I would talk to your counselor before you get the letter, but wait until you get the letter before approaching your professors.